# Check if number typed in input is mathematically valid

Tags: angular, math, angular5

I have previously made input validators to check for email patterns, password min and max length, password confirm and so on.

Now I have something new on my hands that I am kinda stuck and don't know from where to start.

My input has to be 13 numbers and it has to check if inserted 13 numbers contain valid or invalid citizenship id based on algorithm(math result) posted below.

Citizenship id is 13 numbers long and it is the following format:

DDMMGGGRRSSSK

DDMMGGG represent day,month and year of birth in the following example :

1010990 representing 10th October of 1990.

RR represents region of citizen and can include numbers between:

00 to 99

SSS represents numbers for gender for males it must be a number below 499 and for females its above 500.

Now the last number which is 13th number is special control number.

Working CITIZENSHIP ID example below and the algorithm included to get the valid/invalid Citizenship ID:

Example: ID 0308964384007

ZZZ = (0 * 7) + (3 * 6) + (0 * 5) + (8 * 4) + (9 * 3) + (6 * 2) + (4 * 7) + (3 * 6) + (8 * 5) + (4 * 4) + (0 * 3) + (2 * 0) =
  0 +18 + 0 +32 +27 +12 +28 +18 +40 +16 +0 +0 =
  191
191: 11 = 17
  81
  4
11-4 = 7 ====> The ID is correct

Call the sum obtained "ZZZ".
  We divide the "ZZZ" with 11.
  Let's call the leftovers from the operation above "OST".
  We subtract OST from 11 and then we get the difference which we will call "RAZ" (RAZ = 11-OST).

If the rest's value is 1 (OST = 1, RAZ = 10) ID is incorrect

if the rest's value is 0 (OST = 0 ie the ZZZ number is divisible by 11 without the rest) the control digit K is 0
(K = 0)

```
if the residue number is between 1 and 11 (1 <OST <11) the control digit K is the difference between 11 and residue (K = RAZ)
```

If K is different from the "RAZ" ID is incorrect

My mathematics and my mathematical English is not at the top level, but hope someone can figure it out from the math example shown above.

This is the working snippet in javascript:

```
_validateJMBG: function(value, countryCode) {
        if (!/^\d{13}$/.test(value)) {
            return false;
        }
        var day   = parseInt(value.substr(0, 2), 10),
            month = parseInt(value.substr(2, 2), 10),
            year  = parseInt(value.substr(4, 3), 10),
            rr    = parseInt(value.substr(7, 2), 10),
            k     = parseInt(value.substr(12, 1), 10);

        // Validate date of birth
        // FIXME: Validate the year of birth
        if (day > 31 || month > 12) {
            return false;
        }

        // Validate checksum
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            sum += (7 - i) * (parseInt(value.charAt(i), 10) + parseInt(value.charAt(i + 6), 10));
        }
        sum = 11 - sum % 11;
        if (sum === 10 || sum === 11) {
            sum = 0;
        }
        if (sum !== k) {
            return false;
        }


        switch (countryCode.toUpperCase()) {
            case 'BA':
                return (10 <= rr && rr <= 19);
            case 'MK':
                return (41 <= rr && rr <= 49);
            case 'ME':
                return (20 <= rr && rr <= 29);
            case 'RS':
                return (70 <= rr && rr <= 99);
            case 'SI':
                return (50 <= rr && rr <= 59);
            default:
                return true;
        }
    },

    _ba: function(value) {
        return this._validateJMBG(value, 'BA');
    },
```

Hopefully someone can help me with making this done in angular2+ or atleast point me in the right direction.Thank you so much for your time and effort!

What am I trying to achieve?

If I touch the input and insert 13 numbers in my input field I want it to use algorithm posted above to display if ID inserted is valid or invalid depending on the math result.

Comment: Try creating and using a custom pipe with your logic.

Comment: Its very unclear what is being asked, Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I have edited my post. Long story short: If I insert 13 numbers in my input field, I want it to perform math, and based of algorithm posted I want it to check if the ID is valid or invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the right way, and write a custom validator (docs: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators ) for your form (or a pipe), or you can do it the less right way (but reasonably simply) by subscribing to a change in the input, create a local variable for the status, and carry out your function on the value if, and only if, it's 13 characters long.

e.g Component (Add local variable and assign based on result of `validateJMBG`)

```
idVerificationStatus: string = 'Invalid';

checkVerificationStatus(value: string) {
    if (value.length === 13) {
       this.idVerificationStatus = this.validateJMBG(value, 'BA' ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid';
     }
}

validateJMBG(value, countryCode) {
     // paste your code here
}
```

e.g Template (Add `(change)` to your input element)

```
 <input id="yourInput" type="text" (change)="checkVerificationStatus($event.target.value) />
 <div class="verificationStatus">{{idVerificationStatus}}</div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbrpoz

Comment: I can not blame you for not understanding me, since I wasn't that clear. I need to check if 13 numbers inserted in the input field "form" a  valid or invalid ID. A valid or invalid ID is based of a math formula and not just length. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: The code above will do exactly has you asked in your question?

Comment: The line `this.idVerificationStatus = this.validateJMBG ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid';` will assign the value Valid if `validateJMBG` returns true, or the value Invalid` if it returns true.

Comment: `{{idVerificationStatus}}` uses interpolation to display this value, beneath the field. The `value.length === 13` is only there to prevent the function from firing on EVERY keypress. But it will do EXACTLY as you asked in your question...

Comment: I get that, the thing is that the working snippet is in javascript and I have no idea how to change this into angular2 :( I assume I can not just copy paste this in my component ts

Comment: Why not? It's just javascript, just make it a function. I'll edit.

Comment: Well I am new to angular and I was thinking If I just copy paste javascript inside it won't work at all I cant believe I haven't tried it. well let me try it now and I get back to you with results.

Comment: Angular 2 is javascript. It just prefers Typescript. You can mix Typescript and javascript, as TS compiles to JS anyway. I mean, you shouldn't, but you can.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as the right one. Thanks a bunch for taking your time to help me! One more question I can still apply my ngmodel to this input  the event target value is only applied to check if its valid or invalid right? I will play for it a bit to make my submit disabled if it is invalid, but you did the most and thanks again. You made my life so much easier knowing that I can apply my javascript codes in my angular adventures.